# apex 4.0.1 not working

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-apex

I recently upgraded to apex 4.0.1
but when I access 127.0.0.1:8080/apex and login it the page doesn't respong
and another thing ... the page is supposed to have some photos but it doesn't appear
so when I view the source code of the page and open any of the JS files / photos directories / css files

I get this

```
404 Not found
Not found
The requested URL /i/css/apex_4_0.css was not found on this server
```

I have ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Check your web server (Apache?)  It sounds like the web server is off.  A reboot might fix the issue (turn the web server back on).

Comment: restarted apache ... still not working ... rebooted but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two steps to the upgrade. The first is (mostly) installing the APEX_040000 objects. The second uploads a bunch of files into the database.

Make sure you carried out the second step correctly as [documented](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17556_01/doc/install.40/e15513/otn_install.htm#BHAJIGDA)

It is two steps because, if you are using the Oracle Apex Listener or HTTP Server then you'd put those files on a file system somewhere, rather than in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your config file is messed up in some way.  Check the configuration to verify that it is directing traffic on port 8080 to the correct directory.  Here is a link to how to find the Apache config file and how to read it:

http://www.unix-girl.com/geeknotes/apache_virtual_host_conf.html

The only other thing I can think of is that the directory does not exist.  Maybe it got deleted or moved.

Comment: is it weird to fine the httpd.conf empty ?

Comment: apparently debian/ubuntu uses apache2.conf instead